# What is XDG_SESSION_COOKIE, who use it and is it useful for ssh remote login to control local x session?

Tags: xorg

Is it related to DISPLAY? and useful for remotely login a x server to control the local display?

Answer (score 1):

short: not exactly

long: This is an environment variable which may be set for [ConsoleKit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html).  According to its documentation,

> ConsoleKit is a framework for keeping track of the various users, sessions, and seats present on a system. It provides a mechanism for software to react to changes of any of these items or of any of the metadata associated with them.

and goes on to say

> A session is a collection of all processes that share knowledge of a secret. In the typical (or ideal) case, these processes all originate from a single common ancestor.
>
> **As an implementation detail, for now**, this secret should be stored in the process environment by the session leader under the name **`XDG_SESSION_COOKIE`**. When and if we are able to take advantage of a mechanism in the underlying system to store session registration information - we will. However, such a mechanism is not known at the present time.

Noting that the question was asked early in 2014, the [ConsoleKit webpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit/) says (last updated September 2013)

> ConsoleKit is a framework for defining and tracking users, login sessions, and seats.
>
> ConsoleKit is currently not actively maintained. The focus has shifted to the built-in seat/user/session management of [Software/systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) called [systemd-logind](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html)!

In turn, `systemd-logind` says

> **`systemd-logind`** is a system service that manages user logins.

It is not related to `DISPLAY`, but rather to *authentication* needed to connect to a given X server.

Further reading:

- [What is the XDG_SESSION_COOKIE environment variable for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632515/what-is-the-xdg-session-cookie-environment-variable-for)
- [How can I configure dbus to allow ssh-user to suspend server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21586/how-can-i-configure-dbus-to-allow-ssh-user-to-suspend-server)
- [RedHat #771538: XDG_SESSION_COOKIE is set on non-gdm login.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=771538) reported that

  > **`XDG_SESSION_COOKIE`** is set on non-gdm login, preventing proper access to sound (pulse-audio) when using **`startx`**.
- [Ubuntu #302791: ssh not setting XAUTHORITY, XDG_SESSION_COOKIE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/302791) reported that

  > When logging in to a machine through ssh (without -X or -Y), **`XAUTHORITY`** is not set; and when logging in non-interactively, **`XDG_SESSION_COOKIE`** is not set. This prevents programs started over an ssh session to connect to the X server of the machine on which it's running.